# Django serializer's is_valid returning True even if validate returns False

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a POST function like this:

```
    def post(self, request):
    try:

        serializer = CCTDSPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        print("serializer", serializer)
        print("is valid", serializer.is_valid())
```

The Serializer is as follows, its not a model serializer for specific reasons.

```
class CCTDSPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
status = serializers.CharField()
transaction = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
comment = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
tds_id = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())

def check_tds_eligibility(self, data):
    tds_ids = data.get('tds_id', None)

    if tds_ids is not None:
        tds_obj = TDS.objects.filter(id__in=tds_ids, status='open')
        if tds_obj.count() == len(tds_ids):
            return tds_ids
    return None

def validate_status_transaction(self, obj):
    status = obj.get('status', None)
    transaction = obj.get('transaction', None)

    if status == 'closed' and transaction is not None:
        return True
    elif status == 'rejected' and transaction is None:
        return True
    return False

def validate(self, obj):
    validate_status_transaction = self.validate_status_transaction(obj)
    tds_ids = self.check_tds_eligibility(obj)
    if validate_status_transaction and tds_ids:
        print("returning obj")
        return obj
    print("returning false")
    return False
```

The data that I am passing it is:

```
{
    "tds_id":[1],
    "status":"closed",
    "transaction":"ABC",
    "comment":"Boom"
}
```

Now based on the conditions on the data present in the database, it comes to the statement `print("returning false")` i.e. it is returning `False`, but on the view side, the statement `serializer.is_valid()` gives the output as `True`

How come the validate function returns False and the `is_valid` returns `True`?

Answer (score 2):

`validate` method returns validated date or raise error. Since your `validate` method doesnt raise any error `is_valid()` returns `True`. Change method like this to fix:

```
def validate(self, obj):
    validate_status_transaction = self.validate_status_transaction(obj)
    tds_ids = self.check_tds_eligibility(obj)
    if validate_status_transaction and tds_ids:
        print("returning obj")
        return obj
    print("returning false")
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Some error")
```

Comment: @Arjunsingh you are welcome. Dont forget about `validate_status_transaction` method. It should raise `ValidationError` also if you want to see error message as response.

Comment: Yup, did that. Sent the error via serializer.errors. Thanks a lot for saving my day... :)

Comment: It gives an error that transaction: This field is required if I dont pass the transaction in data. But I've set the transaction as allow_null and allow_blank as True in serializer

Comment: @Arjunsingh set also required=False

Comment: I missed that thing again... Thanks a lot bro... :)